# Does the structure morphism matter in GAGA?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, gaga

Let $X$ be an integral Noetherian separated scheme. Can there exist two morphisms of finite type $X\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{C}$ such that the corresponding complex-analytic spaces are not weakly homotopy equivalent?

Comment: If one changes the structure morphism by an automorphism of $\mathrm{Spec} \mathbb{C}$ then the (topological) fundamental group can change (as first shown by Serre).

Comment: Probably related: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-new-users